# I pick a number $n$ and pay you $n^2$. How much would you pay for this game?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory, expected-value

There is an [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243552/i-pick-a-number-n-if-you-guess-it-i-pay-you-n-what-is-the-fair-value-of-the) stating the following question.

> I pick a number n from 1 to 100. If you guess correctly, I pay you $n and zero otherwise. How much would you pay to play this game?

The answer given to question above is 
$$\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac{1}{k}}.$$

---

Let us consider a slightly difference game. If I pay you $n^2$ instead, how much would you pay to play this game?

Intuitively, we should pay more now as we are getting higher reward.

I guess we have 
$$i^2 p_i = j^2 p _j \quad \text{for all }1\leq i,j\leq 100$$
where $p_i$ is the probability of choosing number $i.$
The equations above are obtained from indifference criterion.

On the other hand, we also have 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100} p_k = 1,$$
which implies that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{k^2} p_1 = 1$$

So, the expected payoff is 
$$p_1 = \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac{1}{k^2}}.$$
Is my reasoning above correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right. Note that this is approximately

$$
\frac1{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}}=\frac6\pi\;.
$$

Thus, interestingly, since the sum over $\frac1{k^2}$ converges whereas the sum over $\frac1k$ diverges, this game has approximately the same value independent of $n$ (for sufficiently large $n$), whereas the value of the original game tends to $0$ with $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I see. Do you know of any explanation on why would the modified game has approximately the same value independent of $n?$ This seems interesting.

Comment: @Idonknow:  because, as joriki said, the sum converges.  The sum up to $1000$, say, is not very different from the sum to $\infty$, unlike the linear case where the sum diverges.  The high value for large numbers forces the picker to choose $1$ a lot of the time, whereas in the linear case the value of the game goes to zero as $n$ gets large.